# What are the steps to build a theme for android devices, override the other app's icons, create a special clock, create a side bar apps, java | kotlin

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

[android theme example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9ffo.jpg) check the example, I'm looking for something like that, I just need the steps, libraries, links, courses or anything could help.
thank you for advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You want to make a *launcher* app, so that's what you'll have to search for. You might find some tutorials for the absolute basics, but I wouldn't expect much more than that - you're looking at a fairly large project, especially if you want to add that many components

Comment: @cactustictacs thank you very much, the keyword i needed was "launcher app", and yes i believes that is a large project, but i'm trying to start new things in programming, i will do my best :) ... thank you again :)

Comment: @raulgh well if you're up for it, there's a bunch of Github launcher projects you can take a look at! e.g. https://github.com/topics/android-launcher No idea what they're like or anything, but they're there if you want to see how people did a particular thing

Answer (score 0):

[@cactustictacs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13598222/cactustictacs) helped me in comments, i just need to built a "launcher app" (An app launcher replaces the stock user interface for organizing the home screen and app icons predominantly in the Android world)